# Broken python install: no module named Shutil

Tags: python

I have Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon, Kernel 4.15.0-124-generic.

I had a lot of trial and error with the Python install, I am afraid it is messed up now. Both python and python3 commands work (although they point to different versions):

```
denis@denis-hp ~ $ python
Python 3.7.10 (default, Feb 20 2021, 21:17:23) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
denis@denis-hp ~ $ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But some programs using python, including `pip` (but not `pip3`) raise the following error:

```
denis@denis-hp ~ $ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.compat import WINDOWS
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/compat.py", line 14, in <module>
    import shutil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shutil'
```

I am posting here out of despair after trying numerous things and googling the error without success... thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `shutil` is standard module and it should be installed with `python`. maybe better install `Python 3.7` again - because only installing it again you can install `shutil`

Comment: how did you install it ? There is unofficial Python repo for `Ubuntu` and `Linux` with version from 2.3 to 3.10. See [deadsnake](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) repo. You have to only add repo to the list and install Python with `apt`. I was using it on Linux Mint 19 and now I use it on Linux Mint 20.1

Comment: on my computer `python` still directs to Python 2.7 because some elements in Linux still may need it. And I use always `python3` and `pip3` (or `python3 -m pip install ...`). I have also `python3.8`, `python3.9` and `python3.10` if I need different version. The same with `pip3.8`, `pip3.9`, `pip3.10`s

Comment: @furas I tried to fix stuff, now "python" and "pip" do not work at all, although sudo apt-get python says that it is already installed. Maybe I just need to add an alias or to change the PATH ?

Comment: for `apt-get` word `python` means `python 2`. You can check if you can run `python2`,  `python2.7`, `pip2`, `pip2.7. Check if you have `/usr/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python2`, `/usr/bin/pip2` - (`ls -al /usr/bin/python*`). If you don't have `/usr/bin/python` but there is `/usr/bin/python2` then you can copy (not move) `/usr/bin/python2` to `/usr/bin/python`  (or create link `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python`). You have to install `python3` or  `python3.6`, `python3.7`. You can use `apt` (instead of `apt-get`,`apt-cache`) to check `apt search python3` to see all version.

Comment: thanks, I copied /usr/bin/python2 to /usr/bin/python, everythings seems ok now, at least on the surface...

Comment: I don't know how you install `python 3` before - but now you can try to install `python3` using `apt`. If you want newer version then you may need to add repo [deadsnake](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) but there is no need to install the newest version `3.10` because some modules may still not work with the newest version - better to stay with `3.9` or even `3.8`. Or course you can instal both version and run them as `python3.8`, `python3.9` and the same `pip3.8`, `pip3.9`